# Can I run multiple modules with -m flag?

Tags: python, profile, memory-profiling, cprofile

I want to [profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) my python code with as much parameters as possible:
1. Time (currently with [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler))
2. Memory (currently with [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) or with [profile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-profile))
3. I/O - read/write bytes per second (didn't find any)

The easiest thing to do (as I understand) is to use -m flag on the modules above (e.g. *python -m cProfile [-o output_file] [-s sort_order] myscript.py*)

So, how do I use the -m flag for both the memory_profiler and the cProfile/profile modules?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can use the -m flag with multiple modules. However, it is not difficult at all to use cProfile in your script:

```
import cProfile, pstats

profiler = cProfile.Profile()    # create profiler
profiler.enable()                # start profiling

# do stuff

profiler.disable()               # end profiling

with open('profile.txt', 'w') as fo: # open a file to print the stats
    pstat_profile = pstats.Stats(profiler, stream=fo) # create a pstats object from the profile bound to a file stream
    pstat_profile = print_stats() # print stats to a file
```

This will give you a nice and organized printout of your timing statistics. Now you can run this modified script with -m for the memory_profiler and have both.

I'm not aware of any Python-based tools for monitoring access. However, a Google search for "measuring IO speed" turns up hits all over the place, so you should be able to find a third-party utility (or some built-in tools [like DD](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_I/O_Performance_Tests_using_dd) if you're on Linux) that you can use to track IO performance when you launch the script.

You'll end up running a time-profiled script under a memory-profiler inside of an IO logger, but I think that they should play pretty well together, and their interactions should be pretty easy to spot. For example, your in-script launch of the time profilers will show up as memory allocations in the memory profile, but you'll know you can ignore them.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the measuring of IO speed - my priority is to find this kind of profiler that is not a third party (If it's a third party I will need to sync the different profiler results)

Comment: @TalBarda Unfortunately, I don't think you're going to be able to find that. I just don't think there are any native Python tools for measuring that kind of thing.